# what is wrong with this MYSQL query? Amazon Interview question

Tags: mysql, sql

**Prompt Question** 
Write a query that'll identify returning active users. A returning active user is a user that has made a second purchase within 7 days of any other of their purchases. Output a list of user_ids of these returning active users.

```
CREATE TABLE amazon_transactions(
    id         int,
    user_id    int,
    itemvar    char,
    created_at datetime,
    revenue    int
)
```

My solution is as follows. I'm getting a partially right answer. There are many user ids that should not be there. **Can someone tell me what's wrong with my solution?**

```sql
select
    user_id
from
    amazon_transactions t1
where
    7 < ANY(
        select
            ABS( DATEDIFF( t1.created_at, t2.created_at ) ) 
        from
            amazon_transactions t2 
        where
            t2.user_id = t1.user_id
    );
```

Comment: Please post a linq to a DbFiddle or SqlFiddle with your query and sample data.

Comment: It looks entirely wrong. Why are you using `8 <`? Surely this will find users with a time gap of **at least 8** days? Not "within 7". Also you need to take into account not to compare a transaction with itself. And think about performance. Can window functions be more efficient?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. 8 was a typo. I'm running query with 7 <

Comment: Developers have a blind spot with respect to their own code.  We struggle constantly with this.  Try creating a small test case to test your query.  Try to avoid asking questions you can answer by _"just looking at the result"_.   We sometimes just can't bring ourselves to simply look at the behavior, because _"We just know it's correct, without looking"_.

Comment: @MartinSmith The MySql docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html say it evalutes to `TRUE` or `FALSE` or `UNKNOWN`.

Comment: @Dai `7  < ANY()` evaluates to a boolean but `ANY` doesn't

Comment: yes. `X IN (sub_query)` is just syntactic sugar for  `X = ANY (sub_query)`

Comment: *A returning active user is a user that has made a second purchase within 7 days of any other of their purchases.* Does the user which makes 2 separate purchases on the same day is "returning user"?

Comment: @Akina Yes, they are considered as returning user

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to solve the problem

```
select DISTINCT user_id
  from amazon_transaction a
where exists (select null
                from amazon_transaction b
               where a.user_id=b.user_id
                 and a.id <> b.id 
                 and abs(datediff(b.created_at,a.created_at))<=7
                 )
```

Comment: a.id <> b.id removes the possibility of comparing same transaction.

Comment: yes, if id is the transaction_id and is unique, that would eb the ideal way of doing it

Comment: Thanks it works. Need to enclose dateiff with ABS()

Comment: i fail to understand why you need ABS(), its redundant

Comment: @MartinSmith yes, lead/lag would be my choice as well. If the version of mysql supports it.

Comment: I see the reason why `ABS` is needed. If a transaction is 14 days apart you will get `+14` and `-14` and `-14 < 7`

Comment: We don't know if b.created_at > a.created_at or the other way around. Both the cases will be encountered when the query is executed. Consider datediff('2020-08-10' , '2020-08-20'). This results in -10. Without abs, this case will evaluate to be true but the gap is of 10 days

Comment: got it you are correct ad150

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
select
    t1.user_id
from
    amazon_transactions t1
join amazon_transactions t2
on t1.user_id = t2.user_id and ABS(DATEDIFF(t1.created_at, t2.created_at )) <= 7 and t1.id <> t2.id
```

Or

```
select
    user_id
from
    amazon_transactions t1
where
    7 >= ANY(
        select
            ABS( DATEDIFF( t1.created_at, t2.created_at ) ) 
        from
            amazon_transactions t2 
        where
            t2.user_id = t1.user_id
    );
```

Comment: Every transaction with a not null `user_id` and `created_at` will meet this as there is nothing stopping a transaction matching itself

Comment: The condition t1.created_at <> t2.created_at can be added to the join condition

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the `id` field for that? (though I guess the Q is not entirely clear about how simultaneous purchases should be treated if they somehow exist) Not my DV by the way

Comment: Yes, id can also be used.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM amazon_transaction t1
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM amazon_transaction t2
               WHERE t1.id < t2.id
                 AND t1.user_id = t2.user_id
                 AND t2.created_at < t1.created_at + INTERVAL 7 DAY )
```

The task is slightly ambiguous. Maybe you must adjust the query - for example, use `t1.id <> t2.id`, `t2.created_at <= t1.created_at`, `INTERVAL 6 DAY`...